# Fixed side bar doesn't scroll to bottom

Tags: html, css, django-templates

I have a fixed side bar, that opens as a drop-down when I click a button, but it does not scroll to bottom and the last list items aren't visible.

I have made a template in Django Templates using AlpineJS for interactions:

```html
<div x-data="{ open: (window.innerWidth >= 1024) ? '{{ sidebar_open }}' : false }"
     x-init="$watch('open', value => { if (window.innerWidth < 1024) { if (value) { document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden'; } else { document.body.style.overflow = ''; } } })"
     @keydown.window.esc="open = false"
     class="relative">
  {# Open sidebar button #}
  <button class="inline-flex items-center border gap-2 p-2 px-4" />

  <aside x-cloak
         class="fixed top-0 left-0 lg:top-auto lg:left-auto z-20 w-[18rem] h-full transition-transform lg:transition-opacity duration-200 lg:mt-4"
         :class="open ? 'translate-x-0 lg:opacity-100 lg:border lg:block' : '-translate-x-full lg:opacity-0 lg:hidden'">
    <nav class="h-full bg-gray-50 py-2">
      <button class="text-gray-500 bg-transparent hover:text-gray-900 text-sm p-1.5 py-4 sticky top-0 inline-flex w-full justify-end items-center lg:hidden" />
      <ul class="font-bold overflow-y-auto h-full pb-10" />
    </nav>
  </aside>
</div>
```

This side bar is inside a header:

```html
<header class="w-full bg-white sticky top-0 left-0 flex justify-center border-b z-40 px-4 sm:px-8 lg:px-6">
  <div class="flex justify-between shrink-0 w-full max-w-screen-2xl py-4">
    {# Left Side #}
    <div class="flex flex-col content-start gap-2">
      {# Logos #}
      <a href="{% url "shop:home" %}"
         class="flex flex-1 gap-4 items-center">
        <img src="{% static "shop/assets/logo_1.svg" %}"
          class="h-8 w-auto sm:h-10"
          width="32"
          height="120"
          alt="logo 1"/>
          <img src="{% static "shop/assets/logo_2.svg" %}" class="w-40 h-auto sm:w-44" width="160" height="24" alt="logo 2" />
        </a>
        <div class="flex gap-4 flex-1">
          {% include "shop/components/layout/category_sidebar.html" %}
          {% include "shop/components/layout/header/search_bar.html" %}
        </div>
      </div>
  </header>
```

I couldn't reproduce this on codepen.

When `<ul class="font-bold overflow-y-auto h-full pb-10" />` has `h-full` I can't scroll to bottom.

The second issue is that the sidebar always takes the whole height of the screen, so on bigger screens it just goes on and on, even if it can have a few list items.
When I calculate the height `h-[calc(100%-4rem)] lg:h-[calc(100%-7rem)]`, the sidebar is still as tall as the screen.

I have tried making the `<aside>` into `sticky` or `absolute` but this creates other issues, especially, since the button that opens the side bar is placed near a search bar, inside the header, and when the sidebar opens it pushes the searchbar. I also couldn't make `sticky` or `absolute` scrollable.

I want the sidebar to have the same height as its content. If it has 5 items it should be as tall as those 5 items. I would also like for it to be scrollable.

It seems like a very easy implementation, but I have no clue what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Check your browser inspector to see which style rules are the ones actually in effect. The inspector shows all the style rules which apply to an element, and shows which ones have been overriden by other rules. The results might surprise you. If that doesn’t help you find the problem, then we need to see the rendered output code which is sent to the browser; your template code is less important. Do a view source in your browser and edit your question to include that code, preferably as a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/2518285) which replicates the problem.